# sequelize association hasMany through deletes from the table before Inserting

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to use hasMany using through association using the example here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/2.0/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations

Basically, my models are:

```
User:
User.hasMany(models.Projects, {through: models.Project_User});

Project:
Project.hasMany(models.User, {through: models.Project_User});

Project_User has custom fields:
 status
 is_default
```

The problem is when I try to add to this using

```
 user.setProjects(project).then(function(res){
```

It DELETES records from the Project_User before inserting taking away the previous values present there.

```
Executing (default): SELECT status,is_default FROM `Project_Users` AS `Project_User` WHERE `Project_User`.`UserId` = 26;
Executing (default): DELETE FROM `Project_Users` WHERE `UserId` = 26 AND `ProjectId` IN (1726)
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Project_Users` (`id`,`is_admin`,`ProjectId`,`UserId`) VALUES (NULL,0,873,26);
```

How can I prevent the DELETION from happening???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `addProjects()` instead:

```
user.addProjects(project).then(function(res){});
```